# ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Hi I've been having a probably trying to install the Ruby gem bundle. I follow the directions `gem install bundle` after I receive this message, but it still doesn't work when I type `bundle -v`. I also type

`which bundle` and receive

```
/Users/edmundmai/.rvm/bin/bundle
```

so it exists!! So why does it not work!! Is there something wrong with the mysterious $PATH that I don't get? (I'm a noob).

Here's my .bash_profile:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/bin
export PATH
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

Here's my .bashrc :

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Here's my gem env:

```
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
- RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 194) [x86_64-darwin11.3.1]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  - ruby
  - x86_64-darwin-11
- GEM PATHS:
   - /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd
   - /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
   - :update_sources => true
   - :verbose => true
   - :benchmark => false
   - :backtrace => false
   - :bulk_threshold => 1000
   - "install" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
   - "update" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
- REMOTE SOURCES:
   - http://rubygems.org/
```

echo $PATH

`/Users/edmundmai/.rvm/bin:/Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin:/Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/Users/edmundmai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/edmundmai/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/edmundmai/bin:/Users/edmundmai/bin`

UPDATE
So after trying to go through the RoR tutorial again, I repeated a few of the steps from earlier in the chapter in one of my two terminal windows (let's call them Terminal #1 and Terminal #2). Terminal #2 still doesn't work (the command line isn't on any directory, just the default directory) while Terminal #1 (at my sample_app directory) works. I think `rvm get head && rvm reload` might be the key? But does that mean I have to run that every time I open my terminal? Check out my terminal #1 commands for before and after (I deleted some of the output so that it would be more clear what my input lines were):

```
Edmunds-MacBook-Pro:sample_app edmundmai$ bundle -v
ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.
Edmunds-MacBook-Pro:sample_app edmundmai$ gem install
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
Please specify at least one gem name (e.g. gem build GEMNAME)
Edmunds-MacBook-Pro:sample_app edmundmai$ rvm -v


rvm 1.15.8 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis     <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

Edmunds-MacBook-Pro:sample_app edmundmai$ rspec spec/
No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
........

Finished in 0.36709 seconds
8 examples, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 59500

Edmunds-MacBook-Pro:sample_app edmundmai$ subl .
Edmunds-MacBook-Pro:sample_app edmundmai$ bundle install --binstubs=./bundler_stubs
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
...
...
(**list of stuff)
Using uglifier (1.2.3) 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
Edmunds-MacBook-Pro:sample_app edmundmai$ bundle show bundler
/Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/bundler-1.2.0
```

I'm extremely unclear as to what the $PATH does. If you guys need any more info, feel free to tell me and I'll provide it.

Comment: You've tried `gem install bundle` but have you tried `gem install bundler`?

Comment: @cjc343: The `bundle` gem has `bundler` as a dependency, so it has the same effect.

Comment: @Edmund: Have you started a new terminal or sourced your bash_profile since editing it? Can you paste the output of `echo $PATH` in your shell? How did you install RVM? It's been awhile since I used it, but generally, it's a copy/paste and run setup.

Comment: @cjc343 yeh I tried both, but still get the error when typing `bundle -v`

Comment: @jmdeldin A few hours ago I had the issue with 2 terminals opened, then one of them worked while the other didn't. So I closed both of them and opened 1 new window and it didn't work, and neither did a 2nd one. Ok, I edited it to inclue my echo $PATH. I don't remember how I installed RVM since it was a few months ago, sorry.

Comment: @jmdeldin ok now it happened again. I have two terminals open, and one of them works all of a sudden (bundle exists) while the other doesn't. I'm rereading whatever I typed in my terminal. I'll paste it so you guys can see. Could RVM be the culprit? I suspect  `Edmunds-MacBook-Pro:sample_app edmundmai$ rvm get head && rvm reload`  did the job. But I'm still afraid that if I close the window it'll stop working again.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I think this is the problem: You have bundler installed to a specific [gemset](https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics/), which is why it's only available when you're in your app's directory (I'm assuming there's a `.rvmrc` file in there).

You have a few options:

1. Install `bundler` to a global gemset. `rvm gemset use global && gem install bundler`
2. If you have Homebrew installed, just do `brew install ruby` and avoid rvm altogether. (There's also rbenv and ry as alternatives to rvm, but I just use 1.9.3 across all my apps, so Homebrew is fine.)

For reference, `$PATH` is a shell environmental variable containing a list of directories that hold executables (e.g., `echo`, `ls`, `vim`, etc.). It's intrinsic to shells.

Comment: Thanks for the $PATH reference. I just tried #1 when opening a new terminal and it worked when I typed `bundle -v` (didn't try homebrew though since it worked after #1). You're the best, thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Edmund: Glad it worked! Now the hard part is over, and you can get back to learning Rails :).

Comment: Setting the bundler to the global gemset worked perfectly! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 54):

Sometimes it is just that you are not sourcing rvm correctly, because you are not in a login shell (using screen?).
Type

```
    source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

And use any bundle command.

Comment: This helped me but i have to run this command each time i open new terminal window. How can i avoid this?

Comment: put this line in your ~/.bashrc (if it is not already there).

Answer (score 4):

Add the following line to `~/.bashrc` file

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

then reload the file:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

Even i had same problem,

In server rvm was not selected as default.So

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default

gem install bundler
```

solved my problem

(Problem occurs only when using rvm)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rvm create a separate gemset, which are self-contained bundles of gems.

```
rvm use 1.9.3@myApplicationNameHere --create --default
```

- myApplicationNameHere = change this to your application name
- create = creates a gemset
- default = means use this version of ruby and gemset as default

Here is the link to the rvm site and the relevant section https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics/